deploy the smart contract once then run it on multiple devices
I Created a Token Marketplace Contract in which any user can come and create a erc20 token with name and symbol .I also Created a dapp for this .But I want to deploy the smart contract once then run it on multiple devices. Means i deploy it one machine or device then i want to check it on multiples devices with same contract address of contract. I want to do this because i will give my dapp to QA tester so they can test it .But the contract is needed to deploy on  each machine to works but i want a alternative way so i don't need to deploy on each machine for testing . Is it Possible or Not?

It's possible to deploy a smart contract once and run it on multiple devices. Here's how:
1. Deploy the contract: Deploy the contract to any test blockchain network (e.g., Sepolia).
2. Get the contract address: Note the contract address after deployment.
3. Use the contract address: In your DApp, use the contract address to interact with the deployed contract on any device.
This way, you only need to deploy the contract once, and testers can use the same contract address on different devices to test your DApp.

thanks very much it working

Then please accept it.
